# How to remove and rebuild a docker container

Tags: docker

What are the commands to totally destroy a docker container, but then still be able to build it again using `docker up`?

I don’t want to just take it down with `docker down`, but I want to destroy it totally so it becomes rebuilt when running `up` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer docker rm plus the container Id
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-volumes-and-networks/#remove-one-or-more-containers

Answer (score 1):

To remove and rebuild a docker container do the following.

First, get the container id (or name):

```
docker container ls -a
```

Now you can remove/destroy the container(s) by running:

```
docker container rm container_id
```

Or for multiple containers

```
docker container rm container_id1 container_id2 ...
```

Now you can rebuild it with:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Or for a specific configuration

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-file.yml up --build
```

`--build` may not be needed as it will be the default when it has been destroyed.